# Trying to Use Terraform and ARM to create a Failover Group with Mutliple Databases but Errors out at databases property in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I'm getting errors when trying to pass more than 1 database into the ARM template:

> Error waiting for deployment: Code="DeploymentFailed" Message="At
>   least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment
>   operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details." Details=[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\":
>   {\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\":
>   \"InvalidResourceIdSegment\",\r\n        \"message\": \"\",\r\n
>   \"target\": \"parameters.properties.databases[0]\"\r\n      }\r\n
>   ],\r\n    \"code\": \"InvalidResourceIdSegment\",\r\n    \"message\":
>   \"The 'parameters.properties.databases[0]' segment in the url is
>   invalid.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]

I've tried passing in a comma separated string of IDs and then tried converting the string into an array.  I've tried adding quotes around each individual string.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sqlServerPrimaryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the primary SQL Server."
            }
        },
        "partnerServers": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of names of the secondary SQL Server."
            }
        },
        "partnerResourceGroups": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The list of names of the secondary SQL Server Resource Groups."
            }
        },
        "sqlFailoverGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the failover group."
            }
        },
        "sqlDatabaseName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the SQL Database."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "partnerArray": "[split(parameters('partnerServers'),',')]",
        "partnerRgArray": "[split(parameters('partnerResourceGroups'),',')]",
        "sqlDBNameArray": "[split(parameters('sqlDatabaseName'), ',')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/failoverGroups",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServerPrimaryName'), '/', parameters('sqlFailoverGroupName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "serverName": "[parameters('sqlServerPrimaryName')]",
                "copy": [{
                    "name": "partnerServers",
                    "count": "[length(variables('partnerArray'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "id": "[resourceId(variables('partnerRgArray')[copyIndex('partnerServers')], 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('partnerArray')[copyIndex('partnerServers')])]"
                    }
                }],
                "readWriteEndpoint": {
                    "failoverPolicy": "Automatic",
                    "failoverWithDataLossGracePeriodMinutes": 60
                },
                "readOnlyEndpoint": {
                    "failoverPolicy": "Disabled"
                },
                "databases": [
                    "[variables('sqlDBNameArray')]"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect to get more than one database into the failover group but I get different errors depending on if I send in an array or a string.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentations you should pass in array of database resourceIds to the databases property:

```
    "databases": [
      "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/failover-group-primary-server/databases/testdb-1",
      "/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/Default/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/failover-group-primary-server/databases/testdb-2"
    ]
```

Not sure that is possible with terraform: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11085

Try this to pass in an array: https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/tips-when-using-the-azure-arm-resource-in-terraform

Comment: That's what the current code set is showing, variables converts the string to an array, but it doesn't like the array.

Comment: well, because the array is wrong, pass it as an array in the first place, i doubt you can create a proper array by splitting on `,` due to quotes